# Atom PHP Linter on Remote Development

Tags: atom-editor

I am using Atom Editor and my PHP is installed inside Vagrant. Atom PHP Linter requires php exectuable path. How can i provide the executable path when i dont have PHP installed in my host (Windows Machine).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your setup is.
I have installed atom on Windows, but our code is on a linux machine.

I did the following:

I mapped /home/myname to drive X:\ (or any which is free on windows)

On my linux machine I made a symlink to the executable:

```
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
ln -s /usr/local/bin/php ~/php
```

In settings in Atom, point to X:/php